# How can I open Word document without having to save it first on the Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I am generating word documents from a template, by customizing it for the user using merge field. For example: Name: "User's name". Right now I save the documents on the server using

```
object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oDocName = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test002.doc";
            wordDoc.SaveAs(ref oDocName, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
            ((_Application)wordApp).Quit(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
```

then, i make the document available for download:

```
protected void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\ebimbari\\Desktop\\test002.doc", FileMode.Open);

    int fileSize = (int)fileStream.Length;
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[fileSize];

    fileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, fileSize);
    fileStream.Close();

    Response.ContentType = ContType("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test002.doc");
    Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + "form" + ".doc");
    Response.End();
}
```

The problem is that I don't want the form to be saved on the server. Can I directly open the document of make it avaiable for download? I'm using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word**

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227828/how-i-can-create-microsoft-office-interop-word-document-object-from-byte-array

Comment: @Rikoshay this isn't my case because i'll be working with huge amount of files

Comment: Can you just save it and then delete it after download?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Immediately after it's not working cuz it says 'file is being used by another process.'

Answer (score 2):

Use the magical `IsolatedStorageFile`

**EDIT**: The answer to 'how to have a persistent copy of a file, without actually saving it to the hard-disk', is - Use the magical `IsolatedStorageFile`.

(The word 'magical' may be ommited).

I can't test this code, and not sure how `worddoc.SaveAs(...)` behaves. Please test and let me know:

```
    private static readonly string CACHE =  @"MyWordCache";

    static void PutFile(object wordDoc, string fname)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!store.DirectoryExists(CACHE))
                store.CreateDirectory(CACHE);

            object fullname = Path.Combine(CACHE, fname);
            wordDoc.SaveAs(ref fullname, ...);
        }
    }

    protected bool Downloadfile(string fname)
    { 
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!store.DirectoryExists(CACHE))
                return false;

            var fullname = Path.Combine(CACHE, fname);
            using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile(fullname, FileMode.Open))
            {
                int fileSize = (int)fileStream.Length;
                byte[] Buffer = new byte[fileSize];

                fileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, fileSize);

                Response.ContentType = ContType(fullname);
                Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + "form" + ".doc");
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: could you please be more precise?