# How to load Word document from byte array

Tags: c#, ms-word, extract, office-interop

I have the whole MS Word file itself saved into a byte array.A want to load it the way I would if it was on file system but with the minimal use of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word because it is very slow when it gets the the `.Open(args[])`   part.

Comment: What you want to do./.. You want to read the file .. or Write the file ???

Comment: I want to read its text content.

Comment: I have answered .... check it ...

Comment: Where am I supposed to check it ?

Comment: See Down i have answered and put your file path in that code...you will get the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document object from byte array, without saving it to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227828/how-to-create-microsoft-office-interop-word-document-object-from-byte-array-wit)

Answer (score 4):

Try this....

```
      byte[] bte = File.ReadAllBytes("E:\\test.doc"); // Put the Reading file
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\\test1.doc", bte); // Same contents you will get in byte[] and that will be save here
```

Comment: It still uses filesystem I/O. I believe the author is looking for a solution that keeps the `byte[]` in memory without writing the file to disk?

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way to do it right off-the-bat using **Interop.Word**, as there are no methods supporting byte arrays.

As a viable workaround you can use a temporary file in the following way:

```
// byte[] fileBytes = getFileBytesFromDB();
var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllBytes(tmpFile, fileBytes);

Application app = new word.Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(filePath);

// .. do your stuff here ...

doc.Close();
app.Quit();
byte[] newFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(tmpFile);
File.Delete(tmpFile);
```

Fore additional info, [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/open-edit-word-doc-docx-file-byte-array-c-msword-interop/) on my blog.

Comment: Can we Convert an Application object to byte[] array with saving a file ?

Answer (score -2):

The method `public static byte[] ReadAllBytes(
    string path
)` returns all the file information into a byte array. You dont have to worry about the stream, as the MSDN documentation says: 
*"Given a file path, this method opens the file, reads the contents of the file into a byte array, and then closes the file."*

Check out [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readallbytes) if you want more information