# I have word encoded Base64 string. I want to read the contents only. how to do it?

Tags: c#, arrays, base64, openxml-sdk, memorystream

**plainText** has encoded word document base64 string

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(plainText);
using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
                    }
```

I tried to open word document using OpenXML SDK

```
WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true)
```

But it throws File contains corrupted data error.

I've also gone through [MSDN link OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee945362(v=office.11).aspx)

I've created a word document using this byte[] **buffer**
But what I'm trying to achieve is, read the content present in document without creating(saving) the word document. 
What am I missing ?

Comment: If you want to read it with interop I think you have to save it (maybe delete it right after?)

Comment: Hi @EpicKip thanks for the prompt response.
I'm getting base64 string form web api, 
it's a word document  encoded as base64 string.
I'm trying to read the contents present in it. These all has to be done at client side 
so I cannot save.
Is there any possible ways to achieve it ?

Comment: I don't think its possible see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184616/how-to-load-word-document-from-byte-array

But I think you might be able to save at client if its in the temp appdata folder: `Path.GetTempPath();`

Comment: yeah @EpicKip I understood. But is there any workaround to read content from encoded base64 word document string ? at runtime ?
because when I converted the base64 string to byte array and generated a word document. I can able to see the content.
It would be a great help If you could find solution.

Answer (score 1):

the most likely problem here is that you have not rewound the stream. Either set

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

or use the constructor that accepts a `byte[]`, rather than calling `.Write`:

```
using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer)) {...}
```

Comment: I'm getting "file contains corrupted data" error @Gravell 
but If i save the byte array to file, I can able to see my content 
In my case, I shouldn't save.

Comment: @Sai if the buffer contains the right contents *and* the stream is correctly rewound, then either `WordprocessingDocument` is fundamentally broken, or you are mistaken about one of the previous two assertions (it containing the right contents *and* is correctly rewound)

Comment: I guess buffer contains the right content, because when I generate word file using buffer(byte array). I can able to see my contents. But In my case I should not save the file.

Comment: @Sai and did you rewind the stream?

Comment: I couldn't get you. Can you please tell what do you mean by rewind ?@Gravell

Comment: @Sai the things I've demonstrated in this answer. I don't know how old you are, but if you remember audio / video tapes: when you call `Write(...)`, you are recording data but the tape remains *at the end*. To listen to what you just wrote (`Read(...)` from the stream), you need to go back to the start.

Comment: Sorry @Gravell I thought rewind is a technical term. Yea, I've already set the  ms.position = 0; 
I'm getting base64 string from web api
so my assumption is I'm getting entire document content, styles and references as base64 string. so It works only when I save it as word document. 
I don't know how should I proceed.

Comment: @Sai if it works if you `File.WriteAllBytes` and load it as a file, but it doesn't work with the API, then there's a bug in the API. I would start by raising an issue - ideally with sample data and a minimal repro - on the project site, i.e. where that `WordprocessingDocument` type came from

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell I rectified it. Web API content was corrupted. Now it's working. I just followed the same thing :)