# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word C#

Tags: c#

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to open a Word Document in c#. Is it possible to open without a phyical file which is in a specific path on your hard drive?

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Documents.Open(**FILENAME**);

I have the Input as stream and string.

Is there anyother way to make a file object without saving to hard disk and give the input to the Filename ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate -> Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228022/4268340

Comment: Hi , [link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228022/4268340 This link also saves the tmp file in a **C:\Users\z021505\AppData\Local\Temp** and takes the path as **filename** , My question is is it possible to make a file object without making a physical file in harddisk. @Alex McMillan Thanks

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for the clarification.@Alex McMillan